About dpkg -X command
To extract and display in the /tmp directory the filenames contained in the xserver-xorg-input-libinput_1.4.0-1_amd64.deb package, I used this command:
# dpkg -X xserver-xorg-input-libinput_1.4.0-1_amd64.deb /tmp
The output was as follows
./
./usr/
./usr/lib/
./usr/lib/xorg/
./usr/lib/xorg/modules/
./usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/
./usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
./usr/share/
./usr/share/X11/
./usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
./usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf
./usr/share/bug/
./usr/share/bug/xserver-xorg-input-libinput/
./usr/share/doc/
./usr/share/doc/xserver-xorg-input-libinput/
./usr/share/doc/xserver-xorg-input-libinput/changelog.Debian.gz
./usr/share/doc/xserver-xorg-input-libinput/changelog.gz
./usr/share/doc/xserver-xorg-input-libinput/copyright
./usr/share/man/
./usr/share/man/man4/
./usr/share/man/man4/libinput.4.gz
./usr/share/bug/xserver-xorg-input-libinput/script

I have two questions about the command output:

dpkg -X is supposed to extract files but in the list above only 6 items are files, all the others are directories starting with ./, which would normally mean “current directory”.
there is nothing displayed in /tmp directory: why?

PS1:
/tmp$ ls 
security_state
........
usr
/tmp/usr$ ls
lib  share
/tmp/usr/share/doc/xserver-xorg-input-libinput# ls
changelog.Debian.gz  changelog.gz  copyright

$ dpkg can also be used as a front-end to dpkg-deb(1).....

$ man dpkg-deb
-x, --extract archive directory
 Extracts the filesystem tree from a package archive into the specified directory
....
directory (but not its parents) will be created if necessary....

PS2: I think /tmp/ is not a good choice because the permissions have changed. Next time I will use /tmp/dir/, /dir/ will be created and the permissions of /tmp/ will not change.

cd /usr/tmp then look inside.

yeah, basically its all there try tree /tmp

OK, now I understand how it works.Thank you very muc

I'd refer to this askubuntu answer  which refers to the dpkg manpage

  --instdir=dir
     Set the installation directory, which refers to the directory
      where packages are to be installed.  instdir is also the
      directory passed to chroot(2) before running package's
      installation scripts, which means that the scripts see
      instdir as a root directory.  Defaults to «/».


If you're installing a package, its relative to / unless you tell your system otherwise. I'd assume dpkg will go to that directory, and go from there as the current directory. Now you'd notice its creating the full path to each file - in case the directories in between don't exist, it'll create them, else I assume it fails gracefully and carries on to the next file.
From the same manpage

-X, --vextract archive directory
Extract and display the filenames contained by a package.

Its showing filenames not the output.

I don't want to install this package, I want to compare it with  version 1.1, which is currently installed on my system. First I need to understand the command output.

Yeah, so basically ./ is relative to the set install directory if you did install, and -X shows what's there. Presumably if you ran ls against /tmp you'd see your file?
